# Scala structural type with method where only some params are known

Tags: scala, structural-typing

Given this code:

```
object Testy extends App {

  case class Person(
                     id: Option[Long],
                     firstName: String,
                     lastName: String,
                     address: Address)

  case class Address(id: Option[Long],
                     name: String,
                     number: Int)

  val personOrAddress:AnyRef= Person(Some(1L), "first", "last", Address(Some(1L), "street", 1))
  type HasCopyMethodWithId = _
  val newId = Some(123L)
  personOrAddress.asInstanceOf[HasCopyMethodWithId].copy(id = newId)
}
```

How can I implement 'type HasCopyMethodWithId' so that this code compiles and does not fail in runtime?

I've tried:

```
type HasCopyMethodWithId = {def copy(id: Option[Long]): AnyRef}
```

Comment: I think you can't, these copy methods are different. You would have to create another method like `copyId` that would use copy.

Comment: Could the actual type (not a general structural type) be detected via macros?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The synthetic `copy` method provided by case classes is *one single* method with all arguments of that case class, not an individual overloaded one for `id`, `firstName` etc. Therefore the structural type doesn't match.

You could add an auxiliary method:

```
case class Person(id: Option[Long],
                  firstName: String,
                  lastName: String,
                  address: Address) {

  def copyId(newId: Option[Long]): Person = copy(id = newId)
}

case class Address(id: Option[Long],
                   name: String,
                   number: Int) {
  def copyId(newId: Option[Long]): Address = copy(id = newId)
}

val personOrAddress: Any = 
  Person(Some(1L), "first", "last", Address(Some(1L), "street", 1))

type HasCopyMethodWithId = { def copyId(id: Option[Long]): Any }
val newId = Some(123L)
personOrAddress.asInstanceOf[HasCopyMethodWithId].copyId(id = newId)
```

But then almost certainly better is to provide a static type:

```
trait CopyWithId { 
  type Repr 
  def copyId(id: Option[Long]): Repr
}

case class Person(id: Option[Long],
                  firstName: String,
                  lastName: String,
                  address: Address) extends CopyWithId {

  type Repr = Person
  def copyId(newId: Option[Long]): Person = copy(id = newId)
}

case class Address(id: Option[Long],
                   name: String,
                   number: Int) extends CopyWithId {

  type Repr = Address
  def copyId(newId: Option[Long]): Address = copy(id = newId)
}

val personOrAddress: CopyWithId = 
  Person(Some(1L), "first", "last", Address(Some(1L), "street", 1))

val newId = Some(123L)
personOrAddress.copyId(id = newId)
```

Comment: You have a typo here `type HasCopyMethodWithId = { def copyID`